# How to force fixed sized output from classdef methods in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to define a class in MATLAB which has a method that returns a vector. I want the length of this vector to be able to vary depending on how the class is instantiated, but will be fixed for that particular object. Something to this effect:

```
classdef my_class < handle

properties (SetAccess = immutable)
    out_size
end

methods
    function obj = my_class(out_size_in)
       obj.out_size = out_size_in;
    end

    function fn_output = my_function(obj)
         fn_output = zeros(obj.out_size,1);
    end
 end
end
```

This seems to work fine. However, if I want to generate code which uses this class I am forced to enable support for variable-sized arrays (which I would like to avoid), due to fn_output being determined to be varying in size.

Is there any way to force MATLAB to see that fn_output is of fixed size for a particular object? I can't use a Constant property becuase I want out_size to be different for different objects.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 0):

No. When code is generated, there is no way for the code generator to know the fixed size.

If you have many different fixed sizes, you'll need variable-sized arrays. Otherwise, you might want to develop a separate class for each fixed size.